# how to call select using datamapper

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I am trying to call a select statement using datamapper in sinatra. here is the code..

adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter

adapter.execute("select field3 from db_table where field1 = 'val1' and field2 = 'val2'")

how to scroll through the results. or I want it as a array

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dm-ar-finders plugin which adds support for #find_by_sql method